# subseting a data frame is not working when keyed on an NA value

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this

xx

```
dput(head(xx,10))
structure(list(JobName = c("EXBCV01D", "EXBCV01D", "EXBCV01D", 
"EXBCV01D", "EXBCV01D", "EXBCV01D", "EXBCV01D", "EXBCV01D", "EXBCV01D", 
"EXBCV01D"), Date = c(120820L, 120817L, 120816L, 120815L, 120814L, 
120813L, 120810L, 120809L, 120808L, 120807L), TargetDate = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), .Names = c("JobName", 
"Date", "TargetDate"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I need to grab all the rows that target is not

I am doing this
      xxx<-with(xx, xx[!is.na(TargetDate), ])

I get this:

```
head(xxx)
      JobName   Date TargetDate
2689 EXBCV06D 120820         -1
2690 EXBCV06D 120820         -1
2691 EXBCV06D 120820         -1
2692 EXBCV06D 120820         -1
2693 EXBCV06D 120817         -1
2694 EXBCV06D 120817         -1
```

I am getting multiple  JobName for the same date. Something weird is happening here.

Answer (score 0):

<del>It should be `is.na(....)` not `is.NA(....)`, in the function name the `na` is lowercase.</del>

For example using your data

```
x <- read.table(text = "Date   Process Target
1/1/2012 ftp    -2
1/2/2012 http    -1
1/3/2012 telnet  NA
1/4/2012  ssh    NA", header = TRUE, na.strings="NA")
x <- transform(x, Target = factor(Target))
```

this works

```
R> xx <- subset(x, !is.na(Target))
R> xx
      Date Process Target
1 1/1/2012     ftp     -2
2 1/2/2012    http     -1
```

You can also do this via the usual subsetting routines:

```
R> with(x, x[!is.na(Target), ])
      Date Process Target
1 1/1/2012     ftp     -2
2 1/2/2012    http     -1
```

or

```
R> x[!is.na(x$Target), ]
      Date Process Target
1 1/1/2012     ftp     -2
2 1/2/2012    http     -1
```

Comment: that is not it. I corrected my post. I have lower case na. Somehow, when i use this function, I am getting multiple process names for the same date. Something is wrong. How do I subset a data frame if a header has no NA?

Comment: Then it is a problem with your data - I had to rebuild what I thought was your data as `Target` is stored as a factor from the output you showed. You question about a header not having NA makes no sense to me. Can you post the output from `dput(x)` **into** your question so we can see what you are working with. As I showed, a correctly named function call does work.

Comment: I have update the file that I am working on. I tried all of the above what you suggested but it is not working. I get multible jobnames with the same date. I should be getting unique jobname with each different dates.

Comment: Look at `xx` in your code - what you have pasted is a `Target` that is all `NA` yet you show data that is all `-1`. Something is amiss. Can you give the `dput()` of the data you *show*! and perhaps the output from `str()` applied to your object?

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you might find `complete.cases` handy. You can use this function to drop any rows with `NA`s in any column.

```
d <- read.table(text="Date   Process Target
1/1/2012 ftp    -2
1/2/2012 http    -1
1/3/2012 telnet  NA
1/4/2012  ssh    NA", header=TRUE)

d[complete.cases(d), ]

#       Date Process Target
# 1 1/1/2012     ftp     -2
# 2 1/2/2012    http     -1
```

I'll just add that you're recommended only to use the `subset` function in interactive-mode, and not programmatically in your scripts. Due of the way this function evaluates, problems can arise (See [discussion](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Evaluation)). If you're just testing stuff out, feel comfortable using it. However, if you're writing functions that may be used by other people, err on the side of safety and use the standard `[` subsetting syntax demonstrated in both @Gavin's and my answers.